# Проблема при создании дизайна для программы на C# - WPF (NET.Framework)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

При запуске отладки Visual Studio показвает такую ошибку:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ""Задание свойства "System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style" вызвало исключение.": номер строки "270" и позиция в строке "42"."
>
> Внутреннее исключение
> InvalidOperationException: TargetType "TextBlock" не соответствует типу элемента "ToolTip".

***Код (XAML):***

```
<Window x:Class="Debris_Cleaner.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Debris_Cleaner"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="500" 
    Width="900"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Topmost="True"
    WindowStyle="None"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Window.Resources>
    
    <!-- Стиль шаблона переключение кнопок -->

    <ImageBrush x:Key="tb_mouse_over"
                ImageSource="Assets/mouse_over_btn.png"/>
    
    <!-- Стиль текста -->

    <Style x:Key="font_style" TargetType="TextBlock">

        <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                Value="Fonts/Verdana.ttf #Verdana"/>

        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Center"/>

        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                Value="Left"/>

        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="White"/>

        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="20"/>

    </Style>
    
    <!-- Стиль шаблона всплывающей подсказки -->

    <Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="tt_style">

        <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Right"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#4A5668"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Fonts/Verdana.ttf #Verdana"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="PlacementRectangle" Value="60,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOffset" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalOffset" Value="6"/>
        <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>

    </Style>
    
    
    <Style x:Key="tb_style" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">

        <Setter Property="Template">

            <Setter.Value>

                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">

                    <Border x:Name="border"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    TargetName="border"
                                    Value="{StaticResource tb_mouse_over}"/>

                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    TargetName="border"
                                    Value="{StaticResource tb_mouse_over}"/>

                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">

                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    TargetName="border"
                                    Value="{StaticResource tb_mouse_over}"/>

                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    TargetName="border"
                                    Value="{StaticResource tb_mouse_over}"/>

                        </Trigger>
                        
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    
                </ControlTemplate>
                
            </Setter.Value>
            
        </Setter>
        
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    
    <!--// Цвет фона //-->

    <Grid Background="Black">

        <!--// Панель навигации //-->

        <Grid x:Name="nav_pnl"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Width="65"
              Background="#2E333A">

            <StackPanel x:Name="st_pnl">

                <!-- Cетка для кнопки переключения меню -->

                <Grid Height="90">
                    
                    <!-- Заголовок текста меню -->

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Margin="73,-20,0,0"
                               Text="М Е Н Ю"
                               Foreground="White"
                               FontSize="22"
                               Background="Transparent"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Style="{StaticResource font_style}">
                        
                        <!-- Эффект тени -->

                        <TextBlock.Effect>

                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10"
                                              ShadowDepth="1"
                                              Direction="90"
                                              Color="White"/>

                        </TextBlock.Effect>
                        
                    </TextBlock>
                    
                    <!-- Переключение кнопок -->

                    <ToggleButton x:Name="Tg_Btn"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Margin="18,-20,0,0"
                                  Height="30"
                                  Width="30"
                                  BorderThickness="0"
                                  Style="{StaticResource tb_style}">

                        <!-- фоновое изображение кнопки переключения по умолчанию -->

                        <ToggleButton.Background>

                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/menu_btn.png"
                                        Stretch="Fill"/>

                        </ToggleButton.Background>
                        
                        <!-- проверка переключение кнопок -->

                        <ToggleButton.Triggers>

                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">

                                <BeginStoryboard>

                                    <Storyboard x:Name="HideStackPanel">

                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="nav_pnl"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                            BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                            From="230" To="65"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.2">

                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                        
                                    </Storyboard>
                                    
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                
                            </EventTrigger>

                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">

                                <BeginStoryboard>

                                    <Storyboard x:Name="ShowStackPanel">

                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="nav_pnl"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                            BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                            From="65" To="230"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.3">

                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                        
                                    </Storyboard>
                                    
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                
                            </EventTrigger>

                        </ToggleButton.Triggers>

                    </ToggleButton>
                    
                </Grid>
                
                <!-- Просмотр списка меню -->

                <ListView x:Name="LV"
                          Background="Transparent"
                          BorderBrush="Transparent"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    
                    <!-- Главная -->

                    <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Margin="0,0,0,15"
                                  >

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Width="230">

                            <Image Source="Assets/home_btn.png"
                                   Stretch="None"
                                   Margin="12,0,0,0"/>

                            <TextBlock Text="Главная"
                                       Margin="25,0,0,0"
                                       Style="{StaticResource font_style}"/>

                        </StackPanel>

                        <!-- Всплывающая подсказка -->

                        <ListViewItem.ToolTip>

                            <ToolTip x:Name="tt_home"
                                     Content="Главная"
                                     Style="{StaticResource font_style}"/>

                        </ListViewItem.ToolTip>
                        
                    </ListViewItem>
                    
                    <!-- Инструменты -->

                    <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Margin="0,0,0,15"
                                  >

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Width="230">

                            <Image Source="Assets/instruments_btn.png"
                                   Stretch="None"
                                   Margin="12,0,0,0"/>

                            <TextBlock Text="Инструменты"
                                       Margin="25,0,0,0"
                                       Style="{StaticResource font_style}"/>

                        </StackPanel>

                        <!-- Всплывающая подсказка -->

                        <ListViewItem.ToolTip>

                            <ToolTip x:Name="tt_instruments"
                                     Content="Инструменты"
                                     Style="{StaticResource font_style}"/>

                        </ListViewItem.ToolTip>

                    </ListViewItem>
                    
                    <!-- Настройки -->

                    <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Margin="0,0,0,15"
                                  >

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Width="230">

                            <Image Source="Assets/settings_btn.png"
                                   Stretch="None"
                                   Margin="12,0,0,0"/>

                            <TextBlock Text="Настройки"
                                       Margin="25,0,0,0"
                                       Style="{StaticResource font_style}"/>

                        </StackPanel>

                        <!-- Всплывающая подсказка -->

                        <ListViewItem.ToolTip>

                            <ToolTip x:Name="tt_settings"
                                     Content="Настройки"
                                     Style="{StaticResource font_style}"/>

                        </ListViewItem.ToolTip>

                    </ListViewItem>

                </ListView>
                
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
        
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Стиль `font_style` покажите. У вас ругается на то, что вы у него поставили `TargetType="TextBlock"`, но пытаетесь данный стиль применить к `ToolTip`. И да, это не C# код, а XAML.

Comment: Я выписал весь код, просмотрите

Comment: Ну да, как я и говорил, вы пишете `<Style x:Key="font_style" TargetType="TextBlock">`, то есть говорите условно "Ей, я хочу чтоб этот стиль был доступен только для `TextBlock`!", а потом берете, и делаете `<ToolTip x:Name="tt_home" Style="{StaticResource font_style}"/>` противореча тому, что сами и написали. Вы уж определитесь, чего хотите. Если ваша задача сделать универсальный стиль, который подойдет и под то, и под то, то так скорей всего не выйдет, ибо `ToolTip` и `TextBlock` наследуют разные реализации.

Comment: Вот идем в документацию, ищем так [TextBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock) и [ToolTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tooltip), нас интересует строка "Наследование", смотрите что у них общего. Ближайшим общим элементом у них будет `FrameworkElement`, то есть указав его в `TargetType` вы получите подходящий для обоих контролов стиль. НО! `FrameworkElement` не имеет реализации `FontFamily`, `FontSize`, `Foreground`, которые вы пытаетесь установить. Поэтому выходом у вас будет два разных стиля.

Comment: Я вам кстати советую установить расширение [XAML Styler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TeamXavalon.XAMLStyler2022), которое будет следить за вас за стилем XAML, убирая лишнее, а то сейчас у вас с форматирование жуткие проблемы. Ну и советую подумать про именование стилей, например я именую через точку (`TextBox.Colors.Main`), в вашем случае это было бы что-то по типу `Fonts.MainFontStyle`... `ToolTip.Home`. И да, у вас кстати есть `tt_style` - специальный стиль для `ToolTip`...

Comment: Спасибо большое!